# Default moderated content view has an error message

Tags: views

The following error appears in the default state at Home>Administration>Structure>Views>Moderated content>Edit.

> No valid values found on filter: Content revision: Moderation state.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you try to run update.php?

Comment: Yes. Drupal is 8.7.4 for test in Pantheon. In Pantheon, update.php is executed at the time of deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I compared the views on the newly installed site.
In the "Is not one of" operator, no options were selected.
After setting up the workflow, I realized that I needed to check it.
Thank you.

Comment: update.php runs an update on the pre-installed view. If somehow the update hook was skipped, then you can update it by hand like in your answer, but easier in such cases is to reinstall the view, which you find in /core/modules/content_moderation/config/optional/views.view.moderated_content.yml to copy and paste it into the single import of config UI.